# Code hanging when establishing single mongoose db connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is the code i'm using, it hangs when I try to retrieve report. No error messages or anything. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
var mongoose    =   require("mongoose");
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/campaignDb');
var kochavaRequestModel  =   require("../models/kochava_request_details")
// var download  =   require("./request_status")
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();



function retrieveReport(callback) {
     kochavaRequestModel.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'request_time' : -1 } }, function(err, report) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          callback(null, report);
        }
      });
    };


    queueReport = function(appId){
        retrieveReport(function(err, report) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
            startTime = report.request_time.getTime()/1000 | 0 
            endTime = new Date();
            endTime = endTime.getTime()/1000 | 0;
            startTime = startTime + '';
            endTime = endTime + '';
            args = setArgs(startTime, endTime, appId)
            runReport(args)
        });
    }
```

Comment: add an error handler to mongoose. Aside from that, I don't see how you're using queueReport,

Comment: Ok...so I used 'mongoose.connect()' instead of 'mongoose.createConnection()' and it worked. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Used `mongoose.connect()` instead of `mongoose.createConnection()` and it worked. Not sure why.

[edit] More info.....

After looking into this further it looks like createConnection is best used for multiple connections to with different read/write settings. Since I only wanted a default connection I should have specified that in the createConnection arguments.

```
// single server
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
mongoose.createConnection(uri, { server: { poolSize: 4 }});

// for a replica set
mongoose.createConnection(uri, { replset: { poolSize: 4 }});

// passing the option in the URI works with single or replica sets
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test?poolSize=4';
mongoose.createConnection(uri);
```

[Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: I think that `mongoose.connect()` sets up an internal queue for commands that should be executed once the connection has been established; by using `mongoose.createConnection()`, the responsibility for that becomes the developer's (basically, you have to wait for the connection to be established before you issue database commands).